# How to create a service connection with access to all namesapces in azure kubernetes pipeline?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, aks

I tried to create a service connection to azure kubernetes cluster, but it is asking to provide namespace mandatory.

So I provided one namespace and set the cluster admin option selected.

[image: cluseteradmin enabled]

And in the release pipeline, using this connection, I tried to create a secret but in a different namespace.

But I got error as forbidden during release deployment.

[image: error]

How to create a service connection with access to all namesapces in azure kubernetes pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Trying picking default as the namespace and ensure cluster admin is checked like you said and it should work.
I just set this up for mine [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyZlQ.png) and was able to deploy to the cluster, and as the namespace names are in my manifest files, they are creating OK.